# Get value of object in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with an object. The value of the object is a counter from my database.
I need to make a condition on that object.

```
var_dump($myArray);
```

return

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
object(stdClass)[62]
  public 'count(videos_like.videos_like_id)' => string '5' (length=1)
```

I try to do it like so:

```
if($myArray[0]->count(videos_like.videos_like_id) == '5'){...}
```

But of course I get an error.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather advise you to update your SQL query and replace code:

```
count(videos_like.videos_like_id)
```

to

```
count(videos_like.videos_like_id) AS videosCount
```

hence you won't have this problem.

PS: Even you don't have plain SQL and use any framework - it's definitely possible to provide alias to your count column.